# Pandas GroupBy with CumulativeSum per Contiguous Groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to understand the number of times we are in an 'Abnormal State' before we have an 'Event'. My objective is to modify my dataframe to get the following output where everytime we reach an 'event', the 'Abnormal State Grouping' resets to count from 0.

We can go through a number of 'Abnormal States' before we reach an 'Event', which is deemed a failure. (i.e. The lightbulb is switched on and off for several periods before it finally shorts out resulting in an event).

I've written the following code to get my AbnormalStateGroupings to increment into relevant groupings for my analysis which has worked fine. However, we want to 'reset' the count of our 'AbnormalStates' after each event (i.e. lightbulb failure):

```
dataframe['AbnormalStateGrouping'] = (dataframe['AbnormalState']!=dataframe['AbnormalState'].shift()).cumsum()
```

I have created an additional column which let's me know what 'event' we are at via:

```
dataframe['Event_Or_Not'].cumsum() #I have a boolean representation of the Event Column represented and we use .cumsum() to get the relevant groupings (i.e. 1st Event, 2nd Event, 3rd Event etc.)
```

I've come close previously using the following:

```
eventOrNot = dataframe['Event'].eq(0)
eventMask = (eventOrNot.ne(eventOrNot.shift())&eventOrNot).cumsum()
dataframe['AbnormalStatePerEvent'] =dataframe.groupby(['Event',eventMask]).cumcount().add(1)
```

However, this hasn't given me the desired output that I'm after (as per below).
I think I'm close however - Could anyone please advise what I could try to do next so that for each lightbulb failure, the abnormal state count resets and starts counting the # of abnormal states we have gone through before the next lightbulb failure?

**State I want to get to with AbnormalStateGrouping**

You would note that when an 'Event' is detected, the Abnormal State count resets to 1 and then starts counting again.

[image: End State]

**Current State of Dataframe**

[image: Current State of Dataframe]

Please find an attached data source below:
https://filebin.net/ctjwk7p3gulmbgkn

Comment: Would be helpful if you gave data not an image

Comment: [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) one more time

Comment: You included a picture with a data grid. Is it you current result of your code or the expected result? If it is the current result, add the expected result (and change both to the **text** form).

Comment: @Valdi_Bo The data grid represents the expected output for the column AbnormalStateGrouping.

Comment: @wwnde https://filebin.net/ctjwk7p3gulmbgkn
I have updated my query with sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your source DataFrame has only *Date/Time* (either *string*
or *datetime*), *Event* (*string*) and *AbnormalState* (*int*) columns.

To compute your grouping column, run:

```
dataframe['AbnormalStateGrouping'] = dataframe.groupby(
    dataframe['Event'][::-1].notnull().cumsum()).AbnormalState\
    .apply(lambda grp: (grp != grp.shift()).cumsum())
```

The result, for your initial source data, included as a picture, is:

```
           Date/Time  Event  AbnormalState  AbnormalStateGrouping
0   2018-01-01 01:00    NaN              0                      1
1   2018-01-01 02:00    NaN              0                      1
2   2018-01-01 03:00    NaN              1                      2
3   2018-01-01 04:00    NaN              1                      2
4   2018-01-01 05:00    NaN              0                      3
5   2018-01-01 06:00    NaN              0                      3
6   2018-01-01 07:00    NaN              0                      3
7   2018-01-01 08:00    NaN              1                      4
8   2018-01-01 09:00    NaN              1                      4
9   2018-01-01 10:00    NaN              0                      5
10  2018-01-01 11:00    NaN              0                      5
11  2018-01-01 12:00    NaN              0                      5
12  2018-01-01 13:00    NaN              1                      6
13  2018-01-01 14:00    NaN              1                      6
14  2018-01-01 15:00    NaN              0                      7
15  2018-01-01 16:00  Event              0                      7
16  2018-01-01 17:00    NaN              1                      1
17  2018-01-01 18:00    NaN              1                      1
18  2018-01-01 19:00    NaN              0                      2
19  2018-01-01 20:00    NaN              0                      2
```

Note the way of grouping:

```
dataframe['Event'][::-1].notnull().cumsum()
```

Due to *[::-1]*, *cumsum* function is computed from the last row
to the first.
Thus:

- rows with hours *01:00* thru *16:00* are in group *1*,
- remaining rows (hour *17:00* thru *20:00*) are in group *0*.

Then, to *AbnormalState*, **separately** for each group, a lambda function
is applied, so each cumulative sum starts from *1* just in each group
(after each *Event*).

## Edit following the comment as of 22:18:12Z

The reason why I compute the *cumsum* for grouping in **reversed** order
is that when you run it in **normal** order:

```
dataframe['Event'].notnull().cumsum()
```

then:

- rows with index *0* thru *14* (before the row with *Event*) have
  this sum == *0*,
- row with index *15* and following rows have this sum == *1*.

Try yourself both versions, without and with *[::-1]*.

The result in normal order (without *[::-1]*) is that:

- *Event* row is in the same group with the **following** rows,
- so the reset occurs just on **this** row.

To check the whole result, run my code without *[::-1]* and you will see
that the ending part of the result contains:

```
             Date/Time  Event  AbnormalState  AbnormalStateGrouping
14 2018-01-01 15:00:00    NaN              0                      7
15 2018-01-01 16:00:00  Event              0                      1
16 2018-01-01 17:00:00    NaN              1                      2
17 2018-01-01 18:00:00    NaN              1                      2
18 2018-01-01 19:00:00    NaN              0                      3
19 2018-01-01 20:00:00    NaN              0                      3
```

so that the *Event* row to has *AbnormalStateGrouping* == *1*.

But you want this row to have *AbnormalStateGrouping* in a sequence of
**previous** grouping states (in this case *7*) and reset should occur
from the **next** row on.

So the *Event* row should be in same group with **preceding** rows, what
is the result of my code.

Comment: Thank you so much @Valdi_Bo. That is indeed what I am after; However I don't understand why we have to start our compute sum from the last row through to the first. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: perfect! Thank you for your explanation - this has cleared things up for me!